# How to extend components of this type - PaperTextInput.Icon or Tab.Navigator when using styled components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I noticed that my attempts to extend components like `PaperTextInput.Icon` or `Tab.Navigator` are failing and I'm wondering how am I supposed to extend them? What I'm trying to achieve is replace `PaperTextInput.Icon` with `StyledInputIcon` which extends `PaperTextInput.Icon`. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work.

```
const PasswordInput: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({
    label,
    value,
    error,
    toggleShowPassword,
    hideInput = true,
    ...rest
}) => {
    return (
        <TextInput
            label={label}
            value={value}
            mode="outlined"
            error={error}
            textContentType="password"
            secureTextEntry={hideInput}
            right={
                <PaperTextInput.Icon/>
            }
            {...rest}
        />
    );
};

const StyledInputIcon = styled(PaperTextInput.Icon)`
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: 5px;
`;

export default PasswordInput;
```